# Chrome Media Source Extension Error mp4

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4, media-source

I am trying to use the MediaSource API to append separate MP4 videos to a single source.

Start the server ffmpeg Nodejs:

> 1) ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -movflags
>   faststart+frag_keyframe -g 0 http://127.0.0.1:8092
>
> 2) ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f mp4 -vprofile baseline -b:v 500k -maxrate
>   500k -vcodec libx264 -x264opts level=3.0 -acodec aac -movflags
>   faststart+frag_keyframe -g 0 -ac 2 http://127.0.0.1:8092

Both methods do not work. chrome://media-internals/
I get roughly the same results.

> Player Properties:

```
Property                  Value
audio_codec_name          aac
audio_dds                 false
audio_decoder             FFmpegAudioDecoder
duration                  0.000001
error                     Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=1022 append_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf
event                     WEBMEDIAPLAYER_CREATED
found_audio_stream        true
found_video_stream        true
info                      Audio codec: mp4a.40.2. Sampling frequency: 44100Hz. Sampling frequency(Extension): 0Hz.Channel layout: 3.
pipeline_error            chunk demuxer: append failed
pipeline_state            kStopped
player_id                 93
render_id                 173
url                       blob:http://localhost:8090/ec4511f9-0cc2-441f-a0ee-3f444d9b828d
video_codec_name          h264
video_dds                 false
video_decoder             FFmpegVideoDecoder
```

> Log:

```
Timestamp           Property            Value
00:00:00 00         pipeline_state      kCreated
00:00:00 00         event               WEBMEDIAPLAYER_CREATED
00:00:00 00         url                 blob:http://localhost:8090/ec4511f9-0cc2-441f-a0ee-3f444d9b828d
00:00:00 00         pipeline_state      kStarting
00:00:00 07         duration            0.000001
00:00:00 968        info                Video codec: avc1.64001E
00:00:00 968        info                Audio codec: mp4a.40.2. Sampling frequency: 44100Hz. Sampling frequency(Extension): 0Hz. Channel layout: 3.
00:00:00 968        found_video_stream  true
00:00:00 968        video_codec_name    h264
00:00:00 968        found_audio_stream  true
00:00:00 968        audio_codec_name    aac
00:00:00 972        audio_dds           false
00:00:00 972        audio_decoder       FFmpegAudioDecoder
00:00:00 972        video_dds           false
00:00:00 972        video_decoder       FFmpegVideoDecoder
00:00:00 972        pipeline_state      kPlaying
00:00:00 973        error               Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=1022 append_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf
00:00:00 976        pipeline_error      chunk demuxer: append failed
00:00:00 976        pipeline_state      kStopping
00:00:00 978        pipeline_state      kStopped
```

Everything works with webm, but mp4 does not work.
ffmpeg is not the correct settings?

Comment: I've developed a HTML5 live streaming solution and I know this can be cumbersome. To understand why this is failing I'd advise pulling the stream from ffmpeg by wget or other means and then using any of the tools like Atomic Parsley, mp4dump or even ffplay with verbose tracing to see how the atoms are laid out and what exaclty is at the offset 1022 where Chrome fails. Given this info we could provide more help. If you get the fragmented file you could host it somewhere for public inspection.

Comment: Hi! I am experiencing exactly the same issue on Chrome. have you solved it?